# Swiftui form space and seperator bug

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-form

I would like to place 2 buttons one below the other with a bit space in a form. Just like in this example:
[image]

Currently it looks like this:
[image]

With this code:

```
            Form {
                Section {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Zeit:")
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        TextField(text: .constant(getSavedTimeSting(savedTime: 60)), label: {})
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    }
                    
                    DatePicker(selection: .constant(Date())) {
                        Text("Erstellt:")
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    }
                }
                
                Button {
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Text("Teilen")
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Text("Löschen")
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                .tint(.red)
            }
```

Do you have any ideas? I'd be happy for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. Simply put, there's no way to make SwiftUI's native rowSeparators full-width.

SwiftUI automatically applies insets to rowSeparators for List or Form. You would have to create a custom list view to achieve what you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can put each button into a [`Section`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/section), which will give you this:

[image: A screenshot of the simulator.]

```swift
Section {
    Button {} label: {
        Text("Teilen")
    }
}

Section {
    Button {} label: {
        Text("Löschen")
    }
    .tint(.red)
}
```

Is this what you were looking for? I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately no! This is too much space...